# Android Baseline Profiles - No difference in App Startup Time (StartupTimingMetric)

Tags: android, performance, baseline-profile, macrobenchmark

***This is my Macrobenchmark test to measure StartupTimingMetric***

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class Startup {

@get:Rule
val rule = MacrobenchmarkRule()

@Test
fun measureScrollWithoutBaseline() {
    startup(CompilationMode.None())
}

@Test
fun measureScrollWithBaseline() {
    startup(CompilationMode.Partial(baselineProfileMode = BaselineProfileMode.Require))
}

private fun startup(mode: CompilationMode) {
    rule.measureRepeated(
        packageName = PACKAGE_NAME,
        metrics = listOf(StartupTimingMetric()),
        startupMode = StartupMode.COLD,
        compilationMode = mode,
        iterations = 5,
        setupBlock = {
            killProcess()
            pressHome()
        },
        measureBlock = {
            startActivityAndWait()
        }
    )
}


companion object {
    const val PACKAGE_NAME = "com.xyz"
}
}
```

***I've collected the Baseline Profiles using***

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class StartupProfile {

@get:Rule
val rule = BaselineProfileRule()

@OptIn(ExperimentalStableBaselineProfilesApi::class)
@Test
fun collectBaselineProfileAppStartup() {
    rule.collectStableBaselineProfile(
        packageName = PACKAGE_NAME,
        includeInStartupProfile = true,
        maxIterations = 1
    ) {
        startActivityAndWait()
    }
}

companion object {
    const val PACKAGE_NAME = "com.xzy"
 }
}
```

I've confirmed that Baseline Profiles are present in the APK using APK Explorer in Studio

**assets > dexopt > baseline.prof & baseline.profm**

Also, I've confirmed that Baseline Profile are being applied by checking the log

**Installing profile for com.xzy**

My app Gradle includes as suggested by https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/baselineprofiles/dex-layout-optimizations

```
experimentalProperties["android.experimental.art-profile-r8-rewriting"] = true
experimentalProperties["android.experimental.r8.dex-startup-optimization"] = true
```

---

**Results**

***WithOutBaselineProfiles***

timeToInitialDisplayMs
min 384.5,
**median 430.3**,
max 643.0
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4

***WithBaselineProfiles***

timeToInitialDisplayMs
min 395.7,
**median 445.7**,
max 662.7
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4

Tried the same thing again where the median - withOutBaseline is **523** and withBaseline is **549** for the same iterations (5 times)

---

The good part is **FrameTimingMetric** where I've seen consistent gains when using Baseline Profiles.

**Testing on Pixel 6A, Android 13**

What mistakes might I be making in this situation? Alternatively, is this the highest level of optimization I can achieve?

Comment: Any update to your question? Facing similar issue

Answer (score 1):

I think `maxIterations = 1` might not be enough to capture all the code for Baseline Profiles. You might check the `baseline-prof.txt` file to see if there are classes/methods from your package (as a sanity checkt).

You also can check the first iteration of the system tracing recorded with Macrobenchmark and check `JitThreadpool` for JITting activity. There should be none (or very small amount).

Alternatively, you might add
[`TraceSectionMetric("Jit compiling %", Mode.Sum)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/benchmark/macro/TraceSectionMetric) as a metric to the benchmark to see how much jittin is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue in pixel device , in your mobile go to
settings > turn off adaptive battery
after that do the benchmark definitely u will see improvements
because it fixed for me
and

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).